# Releasing ByteBuf in ReplayingDecoder

Tags: memory-leaks, netty

Under what circumstances is it necessary to explicitly release the 'in' ByteBuf passed to the [decode()](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ByteToMessageDecoder.html#decode-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext-io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf-java.util.List-) method of [ReplayingDecoder](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ReplayingDecoder.html) in Netty 4.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it short never... ReplayingDecoder takes care of releasing `in` if needed. That said if you create a new buffer within the `decode` method you are responsible to either put it into `out` or release it.